# WinJS Navigation Template + ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, navigation, windows-8, winjs

I have started out with the navigation template and tried to put a ListView WinControl into a page (not home.html). Inserting HTML works correctly, the Javascript also executes correctly.

When trying to bind a listview using data-win-options however, I encounter the problem that the Namespace I define in the ready handler in JS doesn't exist yet, so the app throws an exception.

If I define the Namespace before the ready event, there is no exception, but the update to the "public" variable I perfom in the ready handler is not reflected in the ListView, only when I navigate back and into the page again is the ListView filled correctly with data.

The only way I found to make a ListView work for now is to directly update

```
document.getElementById('myListView').winControl.itemDataSource
```

Which really isn't the way I want to go. I'd like the binding to be in HTML.

So to sum it up, what is the correct way to bind a ListView in the Navigation Template? Or am I the only one having this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple moving parts here.

First, because the variable you have your data source is not "Observable" -- it won't notify anyone that it's changed. Thats not something that JavaScript can intrinsically do.

Second, you've passed it via the `data-win-options` bucket -- which just captures the value, and makes no effort to observe it.

There are a few ways to solve this:

a) Leverage the way you've found, but make your variable observable, and transfer the value when it changes by adding a change handler. This isn't declarative as you desire but isn't bad.

```
var yourVariable = WinJS.Binding.as({ dataSource: null });
yourVariable.bind("dataSource", function(oldVal, newVal) {
    document.getElementById("yourListView").winControl.itemDataSource = newVal;
});

yourVariable.dataSource = getMyDataYo();
```

b) Set up declarative binding in the HTML, and call WinJS.Binding.processAll() with a data context.

HTML:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
     data-win-options="{ itemTemplate:... }"
     data-win-bind="winControl.itemDataSource: dataSourceProperty"
</div>
```

JS:
In your ready handler:

```
var dataContext = WinJS.Binding.as({ dataSourceProperty: dataSourceInstance });
WinJS.Binding.processAll(element, dataContext);
```

If you save off the dataContext instance, when you set the `dataSourceProperty` in the future with a new datasource, the listview will reload, and re-layout.

Comment: with my limited understanding, processAll is only called once in the default.html file and anything after then is handled by the navigator.js. There is no processAll in my pages.
Do I have to declare this observable global and change it's values at a per-page basis? Will it recognize when I try to add new properties or does it only observe changes to existing properties?
thanks so far.

Comment: procesAll can be called anytime, anywhere. It takes an element, and walks the dom *down* looking for any data-win-binds.

If you dont want to declare your source globally, why aren't you just setting it in your page.ready?

The code above really is all you need -- nothing in the second method is "global". You only call it once, and then when you assign to .dataSourceInstance in the future "magic" will happen

Comment: To clarify, I want to set it globally, but I don't want to have to set EVERY variable at the start of the app. When I set a global variable in the page.ready, it is too late because the page will already have tried to bind to it and therefore crashed.

Comment: If it global, then it doesn't need to be set in read. Set it in app.start. Nada list view with no data spice, or undefined etc, doesn't crash - it just shows no data. You have all the info for your problem in my post - you can use which ever solution fits your needs most.